# Running dotnet watch run from Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to start run `dotnet watch run` from inside Visual Studio - or some shortcut to run it outside?

I find myself doing this a lot, because I switch between projects fairly frequently:

1. Open a new command prompt
2. cd around until I am in the right project folder (typically 2-4 commands)
3. `dotnet watch run`

I know I can just run F5 from inside visual studio, but debuggin is not what I am after (and that locks a bunch of things).`

My ideal solution is probably a shortcut from inside Visual studio, that opens a command prompt, navigates to the "Startup project" folder and excute `dotnet watch run`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to run **dotnet watch run** from inside Visual Studio for the current startup project:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.Project startupProject = DTE.Solution.Item(((DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as EnvDTE80.SolutionBuild2).StartupProjects as object[])[0]);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("dotnet.exe", "watch --project \"" + startupProject.FullName + "\" run");
    }
}
```